# How to secure Spring MVC REST service json response

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, jsonresponse

I am using Spring MVC and REST web services. When I make a REST service call my Spring MVC controller will return me a JSON response. Everything is fine till now. I have a requirement where I need to encrypt the spring controller response which is a plain text.

For Ex : I will do a REST call like

**http://www.AAAAA.com/app/getNameDetails**

and my response is

**{"name": "Naveen", "email": "naveen@gmail.com", "desg" : "SE"}**

My problem is when I call that URL on the browser then it will simply display the above response in the plain text format.
I want to secure this plain json response which is coming from the spring controller.

Is there any way we can do this or else am I on the wrong path..!!??

Comment: You can also secure the app by using Spring Security and specifying particular Role Which can access your app

Answer (score 0):

The most useful way authorize your url pattern

see this

[Security for Spring Restful Web Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8534407/security-for-spring-restful-web-services)